# Ничегонеделанье — это жуть жуд(ь)чайшая!

Tags: орфография

Нужен мягкий знав?

> Ничегонеделанье — это жуть жуд(ь)чайшая!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корректно: *Ничегонеделан**и**е — это жуть жу**т**чайшая!*

**[Степени сравнения](https://pishugramotno.ru/morfologiya/%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9#:%7E:text=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%3F%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%2C%20%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9.%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%3F%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5.%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%3F%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F.%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%3F%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5.%20%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6)**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**[dic.academic.ru](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/43780/%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9)**:

**жутчайший**
**жутчайший**
кошмарный, ужасающий, чудовищнейший, ужаснейший, страшнейший, жесточайший

**жутчайший**
прил., кол-во синонимов: 8
• дичайший (11)
• жесточайший (4)
• кошмарный (35)
• наижутчайший (3)
• страшнейший (2)
• ужасающий (25)
• ужаснейший (5)
• чудовищнейший (8)

К тому же *ничегонеделание* стоит написать через И:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150090/discussion-on-answer-by------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.